# Membership duration depending on conditions?

Tags: civimember

Is it possible to configure memberships in CiviCRM as follows?

The basic subscription duration is 6 months **AND** it gives members the possibility to attend 10 lessons/events. After having "used" the included lessons **OR** after 6 months the subscription expires and has to be renewed.

I could easily configure the membership expiration after 6 months.

As I'm completely new to CiviCRM: Where can I define the/a second condition (expiration after 10 lessons/events)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards

Comment: I don't think this is possible out of the box. It may be possible using an extension like [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules). Otherwise it may require some custom development.

Comment: I didn't find a good and simple solution until now. CiviRules is very good, but the trigger/condition/actions have to be customized there, too. I'm still working on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the membership normally with a duration of i.e. 6 month/1 year. 
Use the extension [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) to report back the number of events visited per user. 
Implement the Rule (on participant status change >>> attended) in CiviRules and change membership/subscription status to "expired".

Comment: nice solution by sounds of it